# import large dataset (4gb) in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory

I'm trying to import a large (approximately 4Gb) csv dataset into python using the `pandas` library. Of course the dataset cannot fit all at once in the memory so I used chunks of size 10000 to read the csv. 
After this I want to concat all the chunks into a single dataframe in order to perform some calculations but I ran out of memory (I use a desktop with 16gb RAM).

My code so far:

```
# Reading csv
chunks = pd.read_csv("path_to_csv", iterator=True, chunksize=1000)

# Concat the chunks
pd.concat([chunk for chunk in chunks])

pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
```

I searched many threads on StackOverflow and all of them suggest one of these solutions. Is there a way to overcome this? I can't believe I can't handle a 4 gb dataset with 16 gb ram!

UPDATE: I still haven't come up with any solution to import the csv file. I bypassed the problem by importing the data into a PostgreSQL then querying the database.

Comment: Why can't you fill the DataFrame in one go?

Comment: Assuming memory problems, Have you tried Dask or Apache Spark?

Comment: Not sure how to do this.. Can you provide me an example?

Comment: @cricket_007 No I haven't. I thought 4 gb weren't even close to "Big Data"

Comment: It isn't, but you could at least distribute the processing rather than needing to feed the entire file into memory before doing anything

Comment: @cricket_007 Well If there is no other solution I guest that's indeed an option. But for the time I would prefer to exhaust all other solutions available

Comment: Can you show the traceback? Is that all the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read large dataset Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833277/read-large-dataset-pandas/46834540#46834540)

Comment: `pd.read_csv` should be able to handle this natively, you should focus on reducing memory usage via the parameters `usecols`, `dtypes`, and converters for dates/times and other formatted fields. (@LinfordBacon: that's not a good dupe target, it's closed and it has one answer recommending a workaround using sqlite3, which should be a last resort.)

Answer (score 1):

I once deal with this kind of situation using generator in python. I hope this will be helpful:

```
def read_big_file_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
        """Reading whole big file in chunks."""
        while True:
            data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data


f = open('very_very_big_file.log')
for chunk in read_big_file_in_chunks(f):
    process_data(chunck)
```

Comment: Still getting Memory Error. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Just keep reducing the chunk size, eventually, your system will be able to handle it.